# Mysql using GROUP BY and SUM(without group by) in the same query without SUBQUERY. Possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I had a query made up from two tables that have a One to Many relationship.

Products table

| product_id |
| --- |
| 1234 |

Products_destinations table

| product_id | destinations_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2 |

I made a query to select product id ant all the related destinations, which is pretty easy.

```
SELECT
    p.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pd.destinations_id) as destinations_list
FROM
    `products` p 
    INNER JOIN products_destinations pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

The result is:

| product_id | destinations_list |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1,2 |

Now a new table enters the query, that can has a One to Many relationship with product as well. It does not however have any relationshio with products_destinations dable.

Products_prices table

| product_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 200 |

The updated query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pd.destinations_id) as destinations_list, SUM(pc.price) as all_prices
FROM
    `products` p 
    INNER JOIN products_destinations pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
    INNER JOIN products_prices pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

And now the end result looks like this:

| product_id | destinations_list | all_prices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1,2 | 400 |

As you can see the price is showing 400 instead of 200, because of the grouping of two destinations that the product has. Is it possible to count the SUM of the products prices in this type of query? One solution is to use SUBQUERY to count the SUM of prices, however this is just an example and the real tables are super large and full of data... Subqueries increase the query time drastically.

UPDATED:

"count the SUM" is bad english, sorry for that. The problem with this query is that the product price is not correct when there are multiple destinations for the product. For example the product can be related to multiple destinations and can have multiple prices. In the same query I need to select the list of destinations and the Total price of the product. In this example product has one price which is 200, but because I need to retrieve the list of destinations also I have to GROUP BY the product which causes the price to be incremented by each destination also. IF the product would have more prices the results would be even worse. In the end the result should look like this:

| product_id | destinations_list | all_prices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1,2 | 200 |

instead of this:

| product_id | destinations_list | all_prices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1,2 | 400 |

Comment: What do you mean by “count the SUM”?  Do you want to get the value `2` here for this example, because this was based on that there where _two_ records in the JOINed data set? Well _implicitly_, you have that information already … you could “count” how many values `destinations_list` contains, if you need this info afterwards while processing these query results further. Could probably also add `COUNT()` to get that value directly.

Comment: Have you looked at window functions? You could partition by product_id and find some hacky way of adding just first row from given parition, eg. `SUM(CASE WHEN partition_row=1 THEN pc.price ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: I'm pretty confused about _"counting the sum"_ myself, but I feel like all you really want in your result is the actual price of 200. If that is the case, you could replace `SUM` with `MIN` or `MAX` (doesn't matter, because the price depends only on the product, not the destinations, so it will be the same in all the rows that are being grouped). Would be helpful if you specified what `all_prices` is really supposed to contain.

Comment: Does your `Product_prices` table have a primary key column to distinguish between different prices for a same product? Or maybe a composite key on `product_id, price`, meaning there are no duplicate prices for a specific product? If yes then `SUM(pc.price)/COUNT(DISTINCT pc.price)` should work. (or count your PK column if you have one and allow duplicate prices)

Comment: I updated my question. The product_prices, and product_destinations tables do not have primary keys, that is a real problem but cant be changed at the moment.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you should be able to simply divide it by the number of unique destinations: `SUM(pc.price)/COUNT(DISTINCT pd.destinations_id)`, which should work even with duplicate prices

Comment: @domskat Thinking about it some more, it will still break if you have duplicate rows in `products_destinations` :s

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you're running into is that there is a cartesian explosion between prices and destinations. Any time you are joining in any more than one single table that enjoys a 1:M relationship with product, you'll start to multiple the rows; two prices and two destinations will become 4 rows, three prices and 4 destinations will become 12 rows

The simplest solution is to make sure you only join in rows that are 1:1:

```
SELECT
  p.product_id,  pd.destinations_list, pc.sumprices
FROM
  products p 

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(destinations_id) as destinations_list 
    FROM products_destinations 
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(price) as sumprices 
    FROM products_prices 
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
```

You can get away with only doing one of these subqueries, but I don't see much point because you'll only have to group the outer and handle repetition there. It's easier to just handle aggregation on a per table basis so that ultimately you're joining everything on a 1:1 in the outer. Once you have this, run an explain plan and work out how you can wisely index to improve things (you haven't posted any where clauses). I appreciate that you said "without subquery" but you're causing a problem (cartesian explosion) that you're then having to find hacky ways to solve, and that will only go so far; it's better to not cause the problem in the first place than find ways to bodge it up after you've caused it. Don't fret too much about how the query appears; it'll likely be considerably rewritten by the optimizer anyway, so getting the plan of how it's actually executing and tuning the setup for that would be more productive

Comment: Never heard of the term "cartesian explosion", thats great new info! Gonna look into your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT p.product_id,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pd.destinations_id)
        FROM products_destinations pd 
        WHERE pd.product_id = p.product_id
       ) as destinations_list,
       (SELECT SUM(pc.price)
        FROM products_prices pc 
        WHERE pc.product_id = p.product_id
       ) as all_prices
FROM products p ;
```

Note:  This keeps *all* products, even those that might be missing prices or destinations.

This version has the advantage that if you are filtering down the number of products with a `WHERE` clause, then it should have very good performance -- assuming that `product_id` is indexed in the two junction tables.

Comment: This looks interesting.. gonna try it, thanks!